# String length function

Tags: php, function

So, I have this function that should throw an error if the string is less than 2 characters, however, no matter how many characters I use I always get the error.

I must use a function to achieve this.

```
function lc($count) {
    if(strlen(trim($count)) >1){
    }
}
```

goes with

```
$firstname = lc($_GET["firstname"]);
        $firstnameErr = "First name must be at least 2 letters";
        $valid = false;
```

Comment: And what's the error you get?

Comment: Is `lc()` meant to actually return anything, like a true/false Boolean? Because at the moment it will only ever return a null

Comment: The form will displace "First name must be at least 2 letters" upon submit. You can enter as many characters as you want but the message always appears.

Comment: It was supposed to be an easy was for me to check if several of my fields have 2 or more characters... I may not be understanding functions correctly.

Comment: Oh my gosh I feel stupid. So adding return $count=true should fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
function lc($count) {
    if(strlen(trim($count)) >=2){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}




if(!lc($_GET["firstname"]))
{
     $firstnameErr = "First name must be at least 2 letters";
     $valid = false;
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh you are a life saver! I totally see what I did wrong now!

Comment: `if(strlen(trim($count)) >=2){
        return true;
    }
    return false;` can be simplified even further to `return strlen(trim($count)) >=2;`

Comment: @ Mark Baker true that, but difficult for quick code reading

Comment: @volkinc: I disagree. It's far more expressive and readable.

Comment: ...and 1/2 the character count. ;-)

Comment: @Mark Baker as you wish

Answer (score 0):

As Mark says, it doesn't return a value.

```
$firstname = lc($_GET["firstname"]);

//if not true we have an error
if (!$firstname) $firstnameErr = "First name must be at least 2 letters"; $valid = false;

//if greater we return name else return false
function lc($name) { 
    if(strlen(trim($name)) >1){
       return $name;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String Length like a pro:

```
function lc($str) { return (mb_strlen($str) > 1 ? TRUE : FALSE); }
```

The above supports UTF-8 characters (`strlen()` does not), and fits easily on one line. `mb_strlen()` is just as fast as the normal function, but supports multi-byte encodings. Given UTF-8 is the most widely adopted encoding, it's a good idea to make sure your application supports it.